# Insert Ecto model with already existing model as an association

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I have 2 models, `entries`:

```
schema "entries" do
  belongs_to :exception, Proj.Exception
  field :application, :string
end
```

And `exceptions`:

```
schema "exceptions" do
  field :name, :string
end
```

The migration script:

```
def change do
  create table(:exceptions) do
    add :name, :string, null: false
  end

  create table(:entries) do
    add :exception_id, references(:exceptions), null: false
    add :application, :string, null: false
  end
end
```

My goal is to store exceptions that happen in another system. I want the project to be able to store each exception in the second table `exception` if they are not already there and then store the application name and the exception id in the first table `entries`. There will be 1000s of records in `entries` and a handful in `exceptions`.

Assuming `entry_params` uses this JSON format:

```
{
  exception: "NPE",
  application: "SomeApp"
}
```

the method that should create the entries:

```
def create(conn, %{"entry" => entry_params}) do
  exception = Repo.get_by(Exception, name: entry_params["exception"]) || 
    Repo.insert!(%Exception{name: entry_params["exception"]})

  changeset =
    Entry.changeset(%Entry{}, entry_params)
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:exception, exception)

  Repo.insert!(changeset)
end
```

This will print out:

```
** (ArgumentError) unknown assoc `exception` in `put_assoc`
```

If I change the `entries` model to use `has_one` instead of `belongs_to` (and I think belongs_to "feels" bad here. An entry does not belong to an exception, it just has an exception) it throws the following:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (not_null_violation): null value in column "exception_id" violates not-null constraint

     table: entries
     column: exception_id
```

What I want basically to first create an Exception (if it does not exist) and than create a new Entry of a system error and put the previously begotten Exception in the entry as an association.

What is wrong here?

Comment: I dont have time to examine the case but I noticed that you pass your params to create an entry and those are incorrect in the way that your entries dont have the `exception` column, they have the `exception_id` column which should reference the id of the exception. So it should be something like this: `%{"exception_id" => 5, "application" => "SomeApp"}`

Answer (score 4):

- **Typo**. `belongs_to :exception, Proj.Exception` should be `belongs_to :exceptions, Proj.Exception`
- **Association**. Based on the data model in the question, I think the put_assoc is the wrong way around because in the data schema in the question, an *exception* has_many *entries* and an *entry* belongs_to *exceptions*. `Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(entries_changeset, :exception, exception)` should be `Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(exception_changeset, :entries, entries)`

### Attempted solution:

`entries` schema:

```
schema "entries" do
  field :application, :string
  belongs_to :exceptions, Proj.Exception, on_replace: :nilify
end
```

`exceptions` schema:

```
schema "exceptions" do
  field :name, :string
  has_many :entry, Proj.Entry, on_delete: :delete_all, on_replace: :delete
end
```

migration script:

```
def change do
  create table(:exceptions) do
    add :name, :string, null: false
  end

  create table(:entries) do
    add :application, :string, null: false
    add :exception_id, references(:exceptions)
  end
end
```

Assuming `entry_params` uses this JSON format:

```
{
  exception: "NPE",
  application: "SomeApp"
}
```

create or update the `exceptions` and the associated `entries`:

```
def create(conn, %{"entry" => entry_params}) do
  new_entry = Entry.changeset(%Entry{}, entry_params)

  changeset = 
  case Repo.get_by(Exception, name: entry_params["exception"]) do
    :nil -> 
      exception = %Exception{name: entry_params["exception"]} |> Repo.insert!
      Ecto.Changeset.build_assoc(exception, :entries, [new_entry])
    struct -> 
      changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(struct) 
      data = Ecto.Changeset.preload(changeset, :entries) |> Map.get(:model) # Ecto 1.x
      # data = Ecto.Changeset.preload(changeset, :entries) |> Map.get(:data) # Ecto 2.0.x
      Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(changeset, :entries, [new_entry | data.entries])
  end 

  Repo.insert!(changeset)
end
```